no record is processed and all the checkpoint files have inconsistent data
I'm trying to use AWS Glue Streaming ETL job to read and write using trigger.AvailableNow with Kinesis Data Streams as I used with Kafka, but no record is processed and all the checkpoint files have inconsistent data related to startingPosition and iteratorType.
streaming_df: DataFrame = spark \
.readStream \
.format("kinesis") \
.option("streamName", "oxg-cdp-cdc-stream-sbx") \
.option("endpointUrl", "https://kinesis.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com") \
.option("region", "eu-central-1")\
.option("startingPosition", "earliest")\
.load()


streaming_df \
.writeStream \
.option("checkpointLocation", <s3_location>") \
.trigger(availableNow=True) \
.foreachBatch(for_each_batch_funtion) \
.start() \
.awaitTermination()

It seems that availableNow doesn't work properly with Kinesis, but I can't find any oficial documentation stating that.

Here Spark github example: Spark-Kinesis
I also find the official documentation from Spark: Spark Streaming + Kinesis
Hope this can help you.
